# powershell command parameter with spaces

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am trying to call a powershell script using `-command` argument from a batch file. The powershell script accepts an argument which may contain spaces. The command fails to accept argument with spaces.

Here is there the batch file.

```
@echo off
set arg1=%*
call powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command ".\build.ps1 %arg1%; exit $LASTEXITCODE"
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

This is how the batch file is called - `.\build.bat '-testToolPath=as sdaf'`

I am using `-command` instead of `-file` just to return the `LASTEXITCODE`

Comment: Can't test as on mobile but wrapping path in double quotes might sort it: ``".\build.ps1 `"%arg1%`"; exit $LASTEXITCODE"``

Comment: Why don't you just execute the powershell script with your arguments instead of trying to pass the argument to a batch file to pass to the Powershell script?

Comment: The batch file does a lot of other stuff and this is just a subset.

Comment: Have you tried both single and double quotes? either `".\build.ps1 '%arg1%'; exit $LASTEXITCODE"` or `'.\build.ps1 "%arg1%"; exit $LASTEXITCODE'`

Comment: Yes, I did try both, but no luck.

Comment: Run `build.ps1` from the PowerShell prompt, rather than from the `cmd.exe` prompt.

Comment: What about the `build.ps1` script: does it accept a _declared_ parameter `testToolPath` with value `'as sda'`, or uses the [`$args` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#args)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use escaped doublequotes?

```
call powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command ".\build.ps1 ^"%arg1%^"; exit $LASTEXITCODE"
```

Maybe you have to remove the other quotes before:

```
set "arg1=%arg1:'=%"
```